# Regex find digits at the end of multiple strings

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-re

Below is my string, its coming from a stdout.

I am looking for a way to find all the decimal numbers for a sensor. I want to provide my regex pattern "TP1" and would like my return to look like this:

[156.2 , 30]

I am using re.findall()

```
TP1   BCArc                                    156.2
TP2   Max: of output here                      0.01
TP3   some:other example 1 here                30.70
TP1   BCArc                                    30
TP2   Max: of output here                      2.22
```

I can find the end of a string but not with the input: see here: https://regex101.com/r/IyqtsL/1

Here is the code Im trying

```
\d+\.\d+?$
```

Comment: It's a good idea to put your regex/code into the question itself. If regex101 goes down then the question no longer has value to future visitors. Also, the test string in the link looks different -- `Th1c` instead of `TP1`? Thanks!

Comment: enable multiline mode in the flags

Comment: @JanWilamowski can you please explain and show how to do that?

Comment: I added a full explanation as an answer.

Comment: Your question is tagged Python, but you only provide a very basic regex - please share the Python code in which you use this regex, as it will affect the answer you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable Multiline mode through flags: on regex101.com, that option is available on the right side of the pattern input field (where by default you can see `/g`. When using the regex in Python, you can pass flags as the third parameter to `re.findall()`:

```py
import re

sensor = "TP1"
text = """
TP1   BCArc                                    156.2
TP2   Max: of output here                      0.01
TP3   some:other example 1 here                30.70
TP1   BCArc                                    30
TP2   Max: of output here                      2.22
"""
re.findall(fr'^{sensor}\s+\w+\s+([\d\.]+)$', text, re.MULTILINE)
# returns ['156.2', '30]
```

All flags are described in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-contents).

Comment: OP's asking for output as `[156.2 , 30]` though. I don't think the question is clear yet. `re.findall(r"^TP1.+?([\d.]+)$", text, re.MULTILINE)` might be what they're after.

Comment: Yes, this does not solve the exact problem. Every line needs to start with the sensor of interest, this case being "TP1". Return Should only be [156.2, 30]

Comment: I updated my answer to include and parameterize the sensor of interest

Comment: @JanWilamowski I'd add a `^` to make sure the sensor is at the start of the line. You can take all or part of my suggested pattern as an edit since it turns out that was what OP wanted.

Comment: @ggorlen fixed it, thank you! Perhaps you should add another answer since you caught that :)

Comment: No, yours seems sufficient to me. Note that if folks do use the interpolation approach, special regex chars might need to be escaped to avoid surprising behavior, like if the sensor happened to be `"C++"` or something like that which raises `re.error: multiple repeat at position 3`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also just directly split your text.

Given:

```
txt = """\
TP1   BCArc                                    156.2
TP2   Max: of output here                      0.01
TP3   some:other example 1 here                30.70
TP1   BCArc                                    30
TP2   Max: of output here                      2.22
"""
```

You can do:

```
>>> [sl[-1] for sl in (line.split() for line in txt.splitlines()) if sl[0]=='TP1']
['156.2', '30']
```